# Database Migration on Startup

Tags: entity-framework-core, database-migration, startup

I've read a lot of articles regarding database migration on startup and no matter what approach I use my efforts aren't going anywhere.  My main problem that i'm getting is  `no parameterless constructor defined for type startup`

I have my **DataContext** class

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DataContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (options.IsConfigured)
        {
            //means that context has been added during dependency injection and no further action required.
            
        }
        else
        {
            //means context is being accessed during Add-Migration therefore we need to set the options. The whole DI/Configuration process won't have run yet, so need some other way to get connection string.
            //probably below is a bit too fancy, just hardcoding would be fine.  But anyway it seems to work and transfers to different developers machines
            //you must have {Values: { SqlConnectionString : xyz}} in local.settings.json in Unite.FunctionApp project dir

            var localSettingsJson =
                Path.Combine(local.settings.json");

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(localSettingsJson, false)
                .Build();

            options.UseSqlServer(config["Values:SqlConnectionString"]);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {... }
```

My **Startup** Class

```
// register assembly
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

{
// inherit FunctionsStartup
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public Startup(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {

        var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(executionContextOptions.AppDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
            .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

        var sqlConnection = config["SqlConnectionString"] ??
                            throw new Exception("SQL Connection String Not Defined");

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnection));
        _context.Database.MigrateAsync();

    }
}
```

}

If I have my paramaterless DataContext method in my class why am i still getting this issue that it isn't defined?

Comment: `no parameterless constructor defined for type startup` : You need add default constructor in Startup class.

Comment: And you can only inject `ILogger` and `IConfiguration` in Stratup class (because the services isn't configured).

Comment: Don't run migrations on startup, use a script instead.

Answer (score -1):

Add your parameterless constructor before the other constructor in your DataContext class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).